# IsProcessRunning function always returns false

Tags: c++, windows

IsProcessRunning returns always false, why? notepad is 100% running! I even tried the built version but still not working... It's strange, I can't find a solution via Google :/

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <tlhelp32.h>

    using namespace std;

    bool IsProcessRunning(const wchar_t *processName)
    {
        bool exists = false;
        PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
        entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

        HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

        if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry))
            while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry))
                if (!wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, processName))
                    exists = true;

        CloseHandle(snapshot);
        return exists;
    }

    int main()
    {
        if(IsProcessRunning(L"notepad"))
        {
            cout << "Notepad running!";
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "Notepad not running!";
        }
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that process named _notepad_ is running? Not _notepad **.exe**_?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, you don't need to write .exe cause the names are without extension. However i tried it, and it didn't work aswell.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what names are returned, or log the names to a file.

Comment: @user6224954 1) The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the `PROCESSENTRY32` states that `szExeFile` contains `The name of the executable file for the process`, and the extension, is typically part of the name. 2) The small test case that I have written, due to your claim that it doesn't contain the file extension, seems to contradict you, since **all** of the entries returned by `Process32First`, and `Process32Next` contained the file extension (and by adding the _.exe_ to _notepad_, your code said that notepad is running).

Comment: By calling `Process32Next` immediately after `Process32First`, you never check the first process returned (e.g. you are skipping a result).

Answer (score 1):

should be "Notepad.exe"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using namespace std;

bool IsProcessRunning(const wchar_t* processName) {
    bool exists = false;
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry))
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry)) {

            wcout << entry.szExeFile << endl;

            if (!wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, processName))
                exists = true;
        }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return exists;
}

int main() {
    if (IsProcessRunning(L"notepad.exe")) {
        cout << "Notepad running!";
    } else {
        cout << "Notepad not running!";
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how i said, .exe doesnt work for me too, but do you mean "Notepad.exe" or "notepad.exe"?

Comment: just log your entry.szExeFile like the code I pasted, you will know. @user6224954

Comment: Funny thing, my Notepad is running, however it's not in the process list generate by above codes (windows 8.1)